# bootstrap static to fixed navbar jumping on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a little trouble working this one out.
I have a bootstrap navbar that goes from static to fixed when the viewer scrolls past the logo at the top. Everything works fine, except when the navbar reaches the top, it jumps down missing first few lines of content. Can anyone help me solve this?

html

```
<div id="logo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>BIG,</h1>
                <h1>BIG LOGO!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id ="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

css

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

java

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
    });
});
```

[Check the JSFIDDLE example](https://jsfiddle.net/bw0L15ya/)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Include all relevant code in the question, please. Also, I don't see a problem at how the code works now. On Chrome, that is, anyway.

Comment: the moment navbar gets fixed  add `margin-top:50px` to div with id `content`. and remove margin-top when nav bar is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
    });

    $('#nav').on('affixed.bs.affix', function () {
        $('#content').css({"margin-top": "100px"})
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yyLbgh98/1/

Comment: Excellent, Thanks. This works. I am wondering where you got 100px from? I was thinking 50px would work as this is the height of the navbar.

Comment: You've to add another 50px to match the current position of the content.

Comment: @JalapenoJack: Could you mark it as completed, if it answered your question?